# Gradle: program type already present

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to start working with libaums project ( https://github.com/magnusja/libaums ).
I wrote a class Log which mirrors the methods of android.util.Log, yet writes everything into a file (since I cannot get access to debug output stream on android).  I was unable to understand how to build a package out of the module I wrote and include it as a local dependency into the  libaums project ( [Gradle compilation: package not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700496/gradle-compilation-package-not-found) ), so I decided just to import Log.java (which is a com.iglogger package that implements Log class) in both of libaums projects (app and  the actual libaums library). That in turn created a problem on the stage of merging dex files - so that app project depends on both Log class and libaums and yet libaums uses Log class too.

```
13684:09:44:38.705 [ERROR] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
13861:Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
13649:09:44:38.698 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] D8: Program type already present: com iglogger.Log
13685:Program type already present: com.iglogger.Log
13862:Program type already present: com.iglogger.Log
13871:Program type already present: com.iglogger.Log
```

After some research, the solution seems to be that I have to  exclude the dependency on Log.java (i.e. com.iglogger.Log) while importing libaums into app project .  But how exactly I suppose to do that in my case? It seems that I have declare a dependency on Log.java in the libaums project, so that I will be able to exclude it later on..  Right?  If so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem resolved with a removal of the files (com/iglogger) from the app project that depends on lib project.
I.e. the **import** statement in java seems to include not only declaration of packages to use, but, **optionally**, the objects of the packages themselves.